# UnsatisfiableError with fresh Anaconda-2021-05 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I have downloaded and installed `Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh` on a clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04 (nothing else previously modified or installed).

I then go to run `conda update conda` and then (eventually, after a long wait) I get a seemingly impossible `UnsatisfiableError` as follows:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - anaconda==2021.05 -> python[version='3.7.10|3.9.4|3.8.8',build='hdb3f193_5|hdb3f193_0']
  - conda-verify -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']
  - conda[version='>=4.10.1'] -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8
```

It seems like conda is incompatible with anaconda out of the box? From what I can see, there is no version of Python that would simultaneously satisfy these constraints. And even is there was, I cannot install it because I soon as I type `conda install [anything]` then it will be solving environment for ages before throwing an error message. I am surprised that I cannot find more hits about this online, since I am working with the base environment of the latest version of anaconda with a clean install of Ubuntu...

For reference, if I try to install my old version of anaconda instead (`Anaconda3-2018.12-Linux-x86_64.sh`), everything works fine.

Comment: Could you include the output of `conda info` to the question? Did you add any channels to .condarc?

Comment: I have settled for using the latest version of miniconda now, and since it is all working fine, I am reluctant to tinker with anaconda any further. However, to reproduce this problem, I did not change anything -- all of the packages listed in 'conda info' are the default packages shipped, and the only channel in .condarc is the default channel.